# computing the gradient $f(\vec{x}) = \vec{x}^T\vec{x}+c$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

Could a helpful soul tell me if this approach is correct?

I need to compute the gradient $\nabla f$ and find the result and deriviation of 
 $f(\vec{x}) = \vec{x}^T\vec{x}+c$

---

To solve this, I'm using a table in my textbook (*First course in Machine Learning, 2nd edition, p. 23*)): [image]

If above table can be used as I imagine, I get:

$f(\vec{x}) = \vec{x}^T\vec{x}+c 
 \leftrightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{x}}(2\vec{x}+c)$.

Calculating $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{x}}(2\vec{x}+c) = 2$

---

The **result** is 2 and the **derivative** is $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{x}}(2\vec{x}+c)$

Comment: The derivative of constant $c$ is zero, not $c$

Comment: I thought the notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{x}} = 2\vec{x}+c$ = 2 was correct? I excluded some steps

Comment: The derivative is linear so you can compute the derivative if $x^Tx$ and $c$ separately. The derivative of a constant should be very straightforward to compute.

Comment: Thank you for your time! It would just think the answer was 2 and not 2x (I thought I also had to take the derivative of 2x, (2x+c)' =  2, so $\nabla f$ = 2).

Comment: The derivative (or the dual gradient in this case) is the 'best' linear (in $h$)  approximation to $f(x+h)-f(x)$. Just as the derivative of the scalar $t^2$ is $2t$ you should expect to see $x$ in the derivative of $x^Tx$.

Comment: Thank you, copper.hat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x+h) = f(x)+ 2 x^T h + h^Th$ from which we can read off the derivative as $Df(x)h = 2 x^T h$, or
$\nabla f(x) = 2 x$.